# Laravel 5 issue with select drop down

Tags: laravel

The code for the controller:

```
public function index()
{$items = all_list::where('list_code', 'ABC-U47')->get();
//return $items;
return view('partials.curlist', compact('items'));
```

I know this works, I tested it with the return $items statement.
The code for the blade view:

```
</div><div class="form-group">
       <select class="form-control" name="item_id">
        @foreach($items as $item)
          <option value="{{ $item->list_data }}"></option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
```

The view just shows and empty box. I know this is something very simple but, for the life of me I can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to do a `dd($items);` instead of `return $items;`? What do you get?

Comment: I am getting what I need from the controller:

Comment: the return value is:
[{"id":1,"list_code":"ABC-U47","list_data":"A - NO HOTEL REQUIRED"},{"id":2,"list_code":"ABC-U47","list_data":"B - HOTEL SOLD OUT"},{"id":3,"list_code":"ABC-U47","list_data":"C - CLIENT STAYING AT NON CORP HOTEL"},{"id":4,"list_code":"ABC-U47","list_data":"D - STAYING WITH FRIENDS"},{"id":5,"list_code":"ABC-U47","list_data":"E - ONLY HOTEL AVAILABLE"},{"id":6,"list_code":"ABC-U47","list_data":"F - FREE HOTEL STAY"}]

Comment: I think you need to have a text value for your option tag. Like this: `<option value="{{ $item->list_data }}">{{ $item->list_data }}</option>`

Comment: That worked! Many thanks. There is NO way I would have ever figured that out. I'm new at Laravel and need to get up to speed. Again, thanks.

Comment: No problem. I'll post my answer so this can be marked as a complete post.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a text value for your option tag. Like this:

```
<option value="{{ $item->list_data }}">{{ $item->list_data }}</option>
```